# Text to Footnote in InDesign

Tags: javascript, java

I am trying run a script that helps in automatically converting and placing text to footnotes in an InDesign document.
Script:

```js
var scriptName = "Convert text to footnote",
doc, story;

app.doScript(PreCheck, ScriptLanguage.JAVASCRIPT, undefined, UndoModes.ENTIRE_SCRIPT, "\"" + scriptName + "\" script");

//===================================== FUNCTIONS ======================================
function Main() {
 var mEndNotes = doc.textFrames.add( {name:"EndNotes"} ),  
 k, len, cIP, currPara, currFoot, mMarkers;  
   
 app.findGrepPreferences = app.changeGrepPreferences = null;  
 //---------------------------------------------  
 // edit doc.footnoteOption here  
 with (doc.footnoteOptions)   
  {  
  showPrefixSuffix = FootnotePrefixSuffix.PREFIX_SUFFIX_BOTH;  
  prefix = "[";  
  suffix = "]";  
  separatorText = "\t";  
  markerPositioning = FootnoteMarkerPositioning.NORMAL_MARKER;  
  }  
 //------------------------------------------------------------  
 // move endnotes to a separate textFrame  
 for (k=story.paragraphs.length - 1; k >=0; k--)   
  {  
  if (story.paragraphs[k].contents.search(/^\[\d+\]/) == 0)   
   {  
   currPara = story.paragraphs[k].move(LocationOptions.AT_BEGINNING, mEndNotes.parentStory);  
   currPara.words[0].remove();  
   }  
  }  
 //--------------------------------------  
 // create footnote markers  
 app.findGrepPreferences.findWhat = "\\[\\d+\\]";  
 mMarkers = story.findGrep();  
 len = mMarkers.length;  
 while (len-->0) {  
  cIP = mMarkers[len].insertionPoints[0].index;  
  mMarkers[len].remove();  
  story.footnotes.add( LocationOptions.AFTER, story.insertionPoints[cIP] );  
  }  
 //-------------------------------------------------------  
 // fill footnote contents with proper text  
 for (k=0; k < story.footnotes.length; k++) {  
  currFoot = story.footnotes[k];  
  mEndNotes.paragraphs[0].texts[0].move(LocationOptions.AT_END, currFoot.texts[0]);  
  if (story.footnotes[k].characters[-1].contents == "\r") story.footnotes[k].characters[-1].remove();  
  }  
   
 mEndNotes.remove();

}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function PreCheck() {
 if (app.documents.length == 0) ErrorExit("Please open a document and try again.", true);
 doc = app.activeDocument;
 if (doc.converted) ErrorExit("The current document has been modified by being converted from older version of InDesign. Please save the document and try again.", true);
 if (!doc.saved) ErrorExit("The current document has not been saved since it was created. Please save the document and try again.", true);

 if (app.selection.length == 0) {
  ErrorExit("Nothing is selected.", true);
 }
 else if (app.selection.length == 1) {
  if (app.selection[0].constructor.name == "TextFrame" || app.selection[0].hasOwnProperty("baseline")) {
   story = app.selection[0].parentStory;
  }
  else {
   ErrorExit("Please select one text frame, or some text, or place the cursor and try again.", true);
  }
 }
 else if (app.selection.length > 1) {
  ErrorExit("Only one text frame or some text should be selected, or the cursor placed into the text.", true);
 }
 
 Main();
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function ErrorExit(error, icon) {
 alert(error, scriptName, icon);
 exit();
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Whenever I try to run this script in a document containing the following styling and text: [Text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wy0Hh.png)

It generates the following error: 
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOu85.png)

Could anyone help me with the idea of actually what is going wrong with the script? I have faced this problem in more than one file and have no idea about scripting.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Regards,
Aman mittal

Answer (score 0):

please check the installed indesign version and indesign file should open before executing script.